# Merging datasets based on condition in R

Tags: r

I have 2 datsets that I want to merge in R, and I do not seem ot be able to get it working out.
See dataset 1 (technologies) and dataset 2 (options) below. Dataset1 needs the additional data to be added as columns to dataset 2 (as e.g. option 1 costs, option 1 emissions etc).

However, the merge is not one on one as not all the rows in dataset1 require data from dataset2. This is indicated with the yes/no values in dataset 1.

```
Dataset1

Technology  Level   Costs   Emissions   Investment  Option 1    Option 2
Technology1 Low 0.9 0.3 0.4 Yes No
Technology1 Medium  0.1 0.8 0.0 Yes No
Technology1 High    0.5 0.6 0.7 Yes No
Technology2 Low 1.0 0.6 0.2 Yes Yes
Technology2 Medium  0.3 0.1 0.2 Yes Yes
Technology3 High    0.7 0.8 0.5 Yes Yes

Dataset2

Option  Detail  Costs   Emissions   Investment
Option1 Low 0.7 0.6 0.7
Option1 Medium  0.8 0.9 0.1
Option1 High    0.7 0.6 0.2
Option2 Low 0.8 0.8 0.7
Option2 Medium  0.2 0.6 0.5
Option2 High    0.1 0.8 0.0

Final result:
Technology  Level   Costs   Emissions   Investment  Option 1 costs  Option 1 Emissions  Option 1 investment Option 2 costs  Option 2 Emissions  Option 2 investment
Technology 1    Low 0.5 0.3 0.2 0.5 0.8 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0
Technology 1    Medium  0.2 1.0 0.1 0.2 0.7 0.6 0.0 0.0 0.0
Technology 1    High    0.5 0.2 0.1 1.0 0.4 0.3 0.0 0.0 0.0
Technology 2    Low 0.7 1.0 1.0 0.8 0.9 0.5 0.2 0.2 0.6
Technology 2    Medium  0.8 0.8 0.1 0.1 0.4 1.0 0.6 0.9 0.7
Technology 3    High    0.8 1.0 0.5 0.6 1.0 0.1 0.4 0.9 0.5
```

It seems like an if/else would work here, but I do not seem to get the ifelse working here.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you manually write the expected output for the sample given?

Comment: In this example you need to complete Dataset2 with columns from Dataset1?

Comment: The expected output is added to the description.

Comment: I need to complete dataset 1 with columns from dataset 2 (the other way around)

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
Dataset1 %>%
  mutate(help1 = ifelse(`Option 1` == "Yes", "Option1", NA_character_),
         help2 = ifelse(`Option 2` == "Yes", "Option2", NA_character_)) %>%
  left_join(Dataset2, by = c("help1" = "Option", "Level" = "Detail"), 
            suffix = c("","_Option1")) %>%
  left_join(Dataset2, by = c("help2" = "Option", "Level" = "Detail"), 
            suffix = c("","_Option2")) %>%
  select(-help1, -help2)
```

**Output**

```
   Technology  Level Costs Emissions Investment Option 1 Option 2 Costs_Option1 Emissions_Option1
1 Technology1    Low   0.9       0.3        0.4      Yes       No           0.7               0.6
2 Technology1 Medium   0.1       0.8        0.0      Yes       No           0.8               0.9
3 Technology1   High   0.5       0.6        0.7      Yes       No           0.7               0.6
4 Technology2    Low   1.0       0.6        0.2      Yes      Yes           0.7               0.6
5 Technology2 Medium   0.3       0.1        0.2      Yes      Yes           0.8               0.9
6 Technology3   High   0.7       0.8        0.5      Yes      Yes           0.7               0.6
  Investment_Option1 Costs_Option2 Emissions_Option2 Investment_Option2
1                0.7            NA                NA                 NA
2                0.1            NA                NA                 NA
3                0.2            NA                NA                 NA
4                0.7           0.8               0.8                0.7
5                0.1           0.2               0.6                0.5
6                0.2           0.1               0.8                0.0
```

**Datasets**

```
Dataset1 <- structure(list(Technology = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("Technology1", "Technology2", "Technology3"), class = "factor"), 
    Level = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("High", 
    "Low", "Medium"), class = "factor"), Costs = c(0.9, 0.1, 
    0.5, 1, 0.3, 0.7), Emissions = c(0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.1, 
    0.8), Investment = c(0.4, 0, 0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5), `Option 1` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Yes", class = "factor"), `Option 2` = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

Dataset2 <- structure(list(Option = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Option1", 
"Option2"), class = "factor"), Detail = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("High", "Low", "Medium"), class = "factor"), 
    Costs = c(0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.2, 0.1), Emissions = c(0.6, 
    0.9, 0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8), Investment = c(0.7, 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 
    0.5, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```